# como bajar títulos de puntos rojos en gráfica highcharts

Tags: javascript, css3, highcharts

en mi gráfica de highcharts estoy buscando mostrar el texto que se puede apreciar en los puntos rojos (Metas) pero solo muestra el texto en la columna de color verde en las demás solo se ve el punto rojo, no se si es porque los valores del rendimiento y meta son casi del mismo valor, pero igual tienen diferencias, lo ideal seria una forma de bajar un poco esos puntos rojos para que se pueda ver el texto que estos mismos tienen, pero no se como hacerlo.

tengo la siguiente gráfica:

```js
Highcharts.chart('rendimientosall', {
 colors: ['#00ff6c','#03deec','#f5940a'],
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'RENDIMIENTO'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Acumulado'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['190 cantidad: 6', '240 cantidad: 13', '320 cantidad: 5'],crosshair: true,
  
  labels: { style: { color: 'networking', fontSize:'15px' } }
    },
 
 
 
 
 yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    labels: {
      format: '{value}',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Rendimiento (Km)',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
      }
    }
  }, { // Secondary yAxis
    title: {
      text: '',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value} ',
      style: {
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      }
    },
    opposite: true
  }],
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  
  
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'black',
            }
        }
    },legend: {
            align: 'center',
            borderWidth: 0
        },


    series: [{
        name: 'Rendimiento',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: '190',
            y: 112108,
        }, {
            name: '240',
            y: 84289,
        }, {
            name: '320',
            y: 70249,
        }]
    },{
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Meta',
  color: 'transparent',
        data: [83712,72341,69638],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 3,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[5],
            fillColor: 'white'
        },dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
         color: 'red',
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
              let dataLabelText = `<div style="text-align: center;">
              <div>${this.y.toLocaleString()}</div>
              <div>Meta</div>
              </div>`;
              return dataLabelText;
            }
        }
    }],
});
```

```html
<div id="rendimientosall" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; margin-top:20px;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(158,158,158,0.52);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(158,158,158,0.52);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 3px rgba(158,158,158,0.52);"></div>


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
```

El problema es que los puntos Rojos que serian las -Metas- solo se logra ver en la columna verde el valor y el texto de meta, como puedo hacer para que también se vea en las demás columnas y no solo se vea el punto rojo.

Cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.